# Jquery to get group sum of same items in dynamic table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I have a form with dynamic rows in which I need to get group sum of all material blockwise to check the stock. If stock is there simply insert the record otherwise give the error. I have used for loop for getting data from rows but I am unable to get the sum.

I have a temp table in which I am recording the stock like when I do entry of inward of the material it adds that blockwise material quantity in it and when I do entry of outward it subtracts the blockwise material quantity from it.

Now I want to check that amount at time of outward entry so that if stock is not there it will give error.

This is my outward form code in which I want to check the stock under for loop

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{  
    $decript_arry_ar = $_POST['barcode'];
    $quantity_ar = $_POST['quantity'];
    $unit_cost_ar = $_POST['unit_cost'];
    $total_amount_ar = $_POST['total_amount'];
    $batch_ar = $_POST['batch'];
    $machine_ar = $_POST['machine'];
    $matcode_ar = $_POST['matcode'];
    $matname_ar = $_POST['matname'];
    $block_ar = $_POST['block'];
    $bobbins_ar = $_POST['bobbins']; 
    $inwno=$_POST['inwno'];
    $inwdate=$_POST['inwdate'];
    $ref=$_POST['inwref'];
    $cmpname=$_POST['billing_company'];
    $cmpadd=$_POST['billing_address'];
    $res3=mysqli_query($conn,"select series as series from company_master");

    $cm=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res3);
    $res=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT MAX(inward_no) as invno from inward_master where div_id='$sdiv'");
    $inv=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    $cinv=$inv["invno"];
    $ser=$cm["series"]+$cinv;

    $q=$_POST["qtyy_total"];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($decript_arry_ar); $i++) {
      $decript_arry = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$decript_arry_ar[$i]);
      $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$quantity_ar[$i]);
      $unit_cost = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$unit_cost_ar[$i]);
      $total_amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$total_amount_ar[$i]);
      $batch = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$batch_ar[$i]);
      $machine = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$machine_ar[$i]);
      $matcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$matcode_ar[$i]);
      $matname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$matname_ar[$i]);
      $block = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$block_ar[$i]);
      $bobbins = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$bobbins_ar[$i]);
    } 
    ?>
}
```

temp table structure is

```
id | mat_code | block  | quantity
1  |  abc     |   A    |      250
2  |  abc     |   B    |      200
3  |  def     |   A    |      400
4  |  def     |   C    |      450
```

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far and the error message you get.

Comment: Something like: `SELECT barcode, sum(quantity) as total FROM series GROUP BY barcode` . And inwards/outwards `UPDATE series SET quantity = quanity + :value WHERE barcode= :barcode`? Take a bit more time with the question, showing the intial state, the transformation required (in text description), and the final state. Try to avoid intersperse various different queries. Be precise.

Comment: I don't like the idea of two back to back queries.  The first two queries should be merged together.  I never use mysqli escaping, I recommend prepared statements.  Assigning the alias `series` to the column called `series` is pointless.  It is Unclear to me just where your code begins to go wrong.  If you need help with the querying, I recommend that you mock up an sqlfiddle demo for us to play with and let us know what result you desire.